# cannot make angular popup (modal/dialog) accessible because focus stayed on btn which opens popup

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, popup, accessibility, wai-aria

I have been trying make my website accessible for all users, but I cannot deal with popups and forms inside them.

When I click on `<a id="login_btn" role="button">` which opens a popup, focus is still on this button, even if I set focus on first input element in popup with `this.focusedElement.nativeElement.focus();` --> I see that input is focused! But sccreen reader still says that the element where I am is button and I have to click on it (just to remind - I see that focus is on input element). When I click just like screen reader want me to do, then the second modal is opened...

How can I ignore 'login_btn'?

I tried with tab index in several ways - body with `tabindex=0`, then when I open modal, `tabidex = -1` and input inside popup has `tabindex=0`. Maybe different way would be correct?
I tried set disable attribute on 'login_btn', aria-hidden, aria-disabled... with no success.

My modal has role="dialog" and aria-modal="true". What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a timing issue. Perhaps your code tries to shift focus before the modal is rendered. You may be able to resolve that with a timeout function that waits for the modal to render before shifting focus to the first input field.

As for tabindexes, `tabindex=“-1”` should only be added to elements that should never be reachable by the tab key or engaged with using assistive technology (you wouldn’t want to add this to an interactive button or a modal input field). And, you should not have to add `tabindex=“0”` to a native `<input>` or `<button>` element as they should be reachable through tabs already.

Also, if your goal is to make your website accessible to all users, you should avoid disabling buttons or hiding interactive content in the manner you're describing.

Google Chrome Developers has some great resources on YouTube around designing accessible modal dialogs: https://youtu.be/JS68faEUduk